# BCD to binary conversion in assembly language

Tags: assembly

```
 BCD2BIN PROC

      PUSH AX
      PUSH CX
      PUSH BX
      PUSH DX
      PUSH SI

      MOV CL,08H

    LB : 
        SAL DH,1
           JC PRTONE
           CMP CL,04H
           JG SKP3
           MOV DL,48
           MOV AH,02H
           INT 21H
           JMP SKP3

    PRTONE: CMP CL,04H
            JG SKP3
            MOV DL,49
            MOV AH,02H
            INT 21H

    SKP3:  DEC CL
           CMP CL,00H
           JE SKP4
           JMP 040H


    SKP4:   MOV DL,' '
            MOV AH,02H
            INT 21H
            POP SI
              POP DX
              POP BX
              POP CX
              POP AX

            RET  



    BCD2BIN ENDP
```

This is a part of a program for converting a bcd number to a binary number. Can anyone please explain the logic behind this? The instructions, I can understand by looking over the internet, but the logic/algorithm for doing it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is badly designed (slower than necessary, and harder to read than necessary). It's equivalent to this:

```
    PUSH AX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH DX
    PUSH SI

    MOV CL,04H
    SAL DH,4

LB: 
    SAL DH,1
    JC PRTONE

    MOV DL,'0'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H
    JMP SKP3

PRTONE:
    MOV DL,'1'
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

SKP3:
    DEC CL
    JNE LB


    MOV DL,' '
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    POP SI
    POP DX
    POP BX
    POP CX
    POP AX
    RET
```

..which can be improved more:

```
    PUSH AX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH DX
    PUSH SI

    MOV CL,04H
    SAL DH,4

LB: 
    MOV DL,'0'
    SAL DH,1
    ADC DL,0
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    DEC CL
    JNE LB

    MOV DL,' '
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H

    POP SI
    POP DX
    POP BX
    POP CX
    POP AX
    RET
```

..which can be unrolled:

```
    PUSH AX
    PUSH CX
    PUSH BX
    PUSH DX
    PUSH SI

    MOV DL,'0'
    SAL DH,5
    ADC DL,0
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H             ;Display bit 3 as '0' or '1'

    MOV DL,'0'
    SAL DH,1
    ADC DL,0
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H             ;Display bit 2 as '0' or '1'

    MOV DL,'0'
    SAL DH,1
    ADC DL,0
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H             ;Display bit 1 as '0' or '1'

    MOV DL,'0'
    SAL DH,1
    ADC DL,0
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H             ;Display bit 0 as '0' or '1'

    MOV DL,' '
    MOV AH,02H
    INT 21H             ;Display a space

    POP SI
    POP DX
    POP BX
    POP CX
    POP AX
    RET
```

Essentially, all it does is print 4 binary digits (from the lowest 4 bits of DH) followed by a space.

Comment: `MOV DL,'0' SAL DH,1 ADC DL,0` How is this used for displaying the result? Because, while converting bcd to binary, the number is divided by 2 and then remainder is recorded. But, here it is left shifted. Why is that?

Comment: @teesto: If you divide by 2 and use the remainder (right shift and use the carry) you end up with digits in the wrong order. If you multiply by 2 and use the overflow (left shift and use the carry) you end up with digits in the right order.

Comment: @teesto: The `adc dl,0` is like "DL = DL + 0 + carry". If the carry is clear then it doesn't change DL, and if carry is set then DL is incremented.